# How to handle network failure in React-Native, when network is off

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native, reactive-programming

How to handle network failure in React-Native, when device not connected to network.

My scenario is am trying to connect some api, while fetching request if network is disconnected react-native throws **network request failed** error. how to handle this scenario to give the user best user experience.

How to handle Network request failed in a better way.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solutions since this time?

Answer (score 10):

Use [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#content) like this:

```
// Check for network connectivity
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {
    if ( isConnected )
    {
        // Run your API call
    }
    else
    {
        // Ideally load from local storage
    }
});
```

Comment: NetInfo hasn't been fixed since 2016.

Comment: @LingboTang the world has got progressively more depressing since 2016.. NetInfo is just trying to protect you

Comment: @ComethTheNerd isConnected will always return false on iOS and it hasn't been fixed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8615

Comment: Hey , I want to show message whenever net disconnected . i don't want to call it in every api .

Answer (score 1):

Handle the exception using a catch block, from the catch block you can perform the action that handles the exception, may be a redirection or a state change to show the error

```
const url = `your url to be fetched`;
        fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: header
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
             this.setState({
                data:json
              });  
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error) {
        //perform the redirection to the network request slow page or set state to show error
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because of 2 main things:

1. Wrong definition about networks request (`AndroidManifest.xml` or `info.plist`)
2. Interruption while streaming the response or very slow internet connection, or other same reasons...

Just handle this case inside `catch`:

```
try {
  const response = fetch(request)
} catch (e) {
  if (error.message === 'Network request failed') {
    // retry or any other handling like showing alert 
  } else {
    throw e; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use package in React i.e. `npm i react-detect-offline`
`import { Offline, Online } from 'react-detect-offline';` in your app and enclose value to be shown in Online mode under Online else Offline message like Network Disconnected
`<Online>Show Online values</Online>` `<Offline>Network Disconnected</Offline>`

Answer (score -1):

The red screen only display in debug mode. To handle the error in case no Internet connection, can use try...catch block

```
     try {
        let response = await fetch(url, params);
    } catch (error) {
        
        console.error(error);
    }
```

Comment: The handle is not good enough, you catch all errors and not only `network request failed`