# React Native NetInfo always returns offline

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm currently trying to implement some functionality in my react native app where I use information stored locally if the device is offline, and perform a fetch if the device is online.

I used NetInfo after reading this [How to handle network failure in React-Native, when network is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927007/how-to-handle-network-failure-in-react-native-when-network-is-off), but unfortunately I ran into an error where NetInfo always returns offline. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/873), which recommended that I change the host in RCTReachability.m from 'htpp://apple.com' to 'apple.com'.  However, I couldn't find a file with that name in the project directory.  Instead I found the only mention of 'apple.com' in any file, which was in RCTNetInfo.m, which was in the correct form.

Does anybody know a way to fix this problem? Or possibly a different way to go about performing one action if the device is online, and another if the device is offline?

Here's the relevant code:

```
fetchData() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {
        console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
        if ( isConnected )
        {
            fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                store.save('contacts', responseData.feed.entry)
                .then(() => store.get('contacts'))
                .then((contacts) => {
                    this.setState({
                        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(contacts),
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
        }
        else
        {
            store.get('contacts')
            .then(contacts => {
                if (contacts == null)
                {
                    this.setState({
                        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(CONTACT_DATA),
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    this.setState({
                        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(contacts),
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to check if the network is online before sending the request.  Just send the request and handle the error if it fails.

Comment: any advice on how to handle the error? I tried using the .catch((error) => { console.error(error); }); promise but I just got the red network request failed screen like in the first link I posted

Comment: I would probably do the stuff you are currently doing when you detect the network is offline in the error block.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: @Philip I don't have RCTReachability.m file. Where can I get it? I use React Native 0.40.0

Comment: @anivaler sorry about the late response, but I don't think that file exists anymore, as I couldn't find it when I asked my question.  Instead you should follow the advice that dan gave by catching network errors and doing whatever you want to be done when the network is off in the catch block