# React-Native NetInfo always returns No Internet connection

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm currently trying to implement web-service call in one of my react-native app and using [react-native-web-service-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-service-handler) to call `Get` and `Post` Web API.

Please have a look at my function below.

```
getRandomUserList() {    
  WebServiceHandler.get(APIConstants.baseURL, null, null)
      .then((val)=>{
          console.log('callapi: ' + JSON.stringify(val))
          this.setState({data:val})
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('callapi:'+ JSON.stringify(error)));
}
```

`APIConstants` is like below,

```
const APIConstants = {
    baseURL:"https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50"
}
```

I'm calling this function like this,

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getRandomUserList();
}
```

Please find the `WebServiceHandler.get` function as following,

```
static get(url: String, headerParam: Object, parameter: Object){
  console.log('WebServiceHandler:Initiating GET request');

  return new Promise(function(success, failed){
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {
          console.log('WebServiceHandler: Network Connectivity status: ' + isConnected);
          if (!isConnected) {
            failed({name:'503',message:"No Internet connection"});
          }else {
            let URL = url + WebServiceHandler.parameter(parameter);
            console.log('URL:-' + URL);
            fetch(URL,{
              method: 'get',
              'headers': WebServiceHandler.header(headerParam)
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response.status);
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw {name:response.status,message:"http request failed", value:response.json()};
                }
                return response.json();

            })
            .then(function(jsonResponse) {
              console.log('************************ HTTP GET Succes ************************ ');
              success(jsonResponse);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('************************ HTTP GET Failed **************************');
                  failed(err)
            });
          }
        });
  });
}
```

It always returns with the following output,

```
WebServiceHandler: Network Connectivity status: false
App.js:50 callapi:{"name":"503","message":"No Internet connection"}
```

I have tried a lot on Wi-Fi as well as broadband connection, no success.

After a research, I found [this article on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8615) and implemented this function as well.

```
static isNetworkConnected() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS = isConnected => {
        NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS);
        resolve(isConnected);
      };
      NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS);
    });
  }
  return NetInfo.isConnected.getConnectionInfo();
}
```

but still it gives me same error message. can any help me how to solve this issue?

FYI. You can find the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730904/react-native-netinfo-always-returns-offline) over here without answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer, workaround will be like this,

```
static isNetworkConnected() {
      return NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then(reachability => {
        if (reachability === 'unknown') {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            const handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS = isConnected => {
              NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS);
              resolve(isConnected);
            };
            NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', handleFirstConnectivityChangeIOS);
          });
        }
        reachability = reachability.toLowerCase();
        return (reachability !== 'none' && reachability !== 'unknown');
      });
}
```

We should implement `getConnectionInfo()` as `fetch()` is deprecated method.

Or

Update the `NetInfo.isConnected.fetch()` with `NetInfo.getConnectionInfo()`. this will also work.

Thanks.